# Trouble getting hotspot to route through VPN

Tags: vpn

I'm currently trying to install a hotspot on raspberry pi for my smart room devices at university, but I can't seem to get the hotspot to route through my remote access vpn given by the university for the hotspot itself. The vpn protocol is Cisco AnyConnect so I'm using openconnect on my computer but this does not route through to my wireless hotspot. Any ideas on what I could do? This the code I'm using to run the hotspot at the moment. The hotspot itself works but the vpn does not so any device that I use is just redirected to the university login page which requires a vpn.

Comment: I do not understand your setup. You have a Raspberry Pi running at home that is wired connected (eth0) to your home internet router. This RasPi establishes also an access point. On the RasPi there is an VPN tunnel to the university network. Devices connected to the RasPis access point at home should be able to connect to smart room devices at university. Can you please confirm or correct this?